# How can I convert Angular object containing nested child objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

I'm working on angular project and I need to be able to extract and modify the formData  before posting it to the serverside as JSON.

**Source data**

```
{
"BioData":{
  "firstname": "Greg",
   "lastName": "John"
},
 "locationData":{
  "locationList":[
  {
    "address1": "22 roackfield",
     "address2": "30 Grandall view",
      "ContactData":{
      contactList:[
      {
        phone: "658884888",
        extension: "555",
      },
      {
        phone: "658884888",
        extension: "555",
      }
      ]
      
      }
  },
  {
    "address1": "102 Mockview",
     "address2": "730 Trunder str",
      "ContactData":{
      contactList:[
      {
        phone: "9999999",
        extension: "333",
      },
          {
        phone: "97874747646",
        extension: "000",
      }
      ]
      
      }
  }
  ]
 },
}
```

I have tried forEach and recursive method of accessing object and arrays, not achieving my desired result

**Modify Data should be in this format shown below**

```
{
"BioData":{"firstname": "Greg",.......},


 "locationData":[ 
       {
         "address1: "22 roackfield",
         "address2": "30 Grandall view",

         "contactList":[{obj1}, {obj2} .....]                
       },
       {
         "address1: "22 roackfield",
         "address2": "30 Grandall view",

         "contactList":[{obj1}, {obj2} .....]         
     
       }
      ]
  
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of what you have tried? And the result you shared have 2 different object name, phoneList and contactList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed few of the property name as the standard naming convention was not followed. If you want to keep them your way you just need to make some simple changes in the code.

I created the following interfaces and made those properties optional so that I don't have to initialize

```html
interface BioData {
    firstName?: string,
    lastName?: string
}

interface PhoneList {
    phone?: string,
    extension?: string
}

interface LocationData {
    address1?: string,
    address2?: string,
    phoneList?: PhoneList[]
}

interface EmployeeDetails {
    bioData: BioData,
    locationData: LocationData[];
}
```

Based on your requirement I used the following way. It is a crude code written in a short time. Please feel free to tweak around the code if you need to. This is just to give you an idea. Please mark it as answer if it helps you find a way. Happy Coding :)

```html
let result: EmployeeDetails = { bioData: {}, locationData: [] };
result.bioData = { ...actual.bioData };
result.locationData = actual.locationData.locationList.map(x => {
    return {
        address1: x.address1,
        address2: x.address2,
        phoneList: x.contactData.contactList
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much @Sudipto Mukherjee. Your suggested solution works!. 

Merci beacoup

Comment: @PCoder can you please mark it as answer? It will help all future developers who have the same type of query to find the answer easily. You need to click the tick icon that is at the top left side of my answer